# Вывести строки содержащие числа через запятую в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такая таблица в mysql:

```
user   || user_id || numbers

test   |    1    | 1,5,10 
test2  |    2    | 5,6,7 
test3  |    3    | 2,6,7
```

Как выбрать строки, где numbers содержит число 6 (исключая 16, 26 и т.д.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET(6, numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если решать задачу в лоб, то можно просто перечислить все возможные варианты, при которых встречается 6:

```
select * from table t
where t.numbers = '6'
   OR t.numbers like '6,%'
   OR t.numbers like '%,6,%'
   OR t.numbers like '%,6'
```